# The # in my google oauth2 authorization request callback url

Tags: php, oauth

I'm making an OpenID/oauth2 login. I am so close to the end game with this login stuff, I smell victory is at hand.

I guess I'm squeezing two questions into one.

I'm making an authorization request like this:

```
if (!isset($_REQUEST['code']))
    {
        $login_path = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?";
        $login_path .= "redirect_uri=" . $redirect_uri;
        $login_path .= "&response_type=token";
        $login_path .= "&client_id=" . $client_id;
        $login_path .= "&approval_prompt=force";
        $login_path .= "&scope=" . $scope;
        $login_path .= "&access_type=online";
        $login_path .= "&state=".base64_encode(strtr("cid=fffffff1", '-_,', '+/='));

        echo "<a href='" . $login_path . "'>login</a>";
    }
```

Note the last appendage to the login_path string, where I'm sending some base64encoded state parameters.

After the user authorizes Google to give my app permission to see who they are, it transports the user to my callback url, and it seems to append url variables to the callback url. These variables include my state paramters, which I'm happy about.

What I'm not happy about is that **instead of delimiting the beginning of the query string with a "?", it uses a hashtag, "#"**, so the string looks like this:

```
http://www.talqo.com/oauth2callback.php#state=Y2lkPWZmZmZmZmYx&access_token=ya29.AHES6ZQ4LB22t7z0Wc8-5uACj_suJ8WnQJxKq9ICdvYT&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600
```

(I changed some of the characters in the access_token above, in case there's some kind of security issue?)

So, you see immediately following the oauth2callback.php is a "#". I can't parse the GET variables.

**And weaseling in question 2)** If you can answer that, I have a followup question, which is that I'm not getting an id with my final authorization request, but instead getting

```
{ "error" : "invalid_request" }
```

I am, however, getting the other access_token, id_token, token_type, and expires_in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops! In the initial login page, I changed:

```
$login_path .= "&response_type=token";
```

to:

```
$login_path .= "&response_type=code";
```

...and now my callback address reads properly:

```
http://www.talqo.com/oauth2callback.php?state=Y2lkPWZmZmZmZmYx&code=4/QX4ZWs1ZDvManJ1x74pIGCOB0BQL.guKNfSajhLQfshQV0ieZDAow_X8UfgI
```

Still, I continue to get a

```
{ "error" : "invalid_request" }
```

instead of the desired "id".